# Change EditText setError drawable gravity

Tags: android, android-edittext, right-to-left

For EditText that going be filled with RTL text, is there a way to change the gravity of the error drawable (and popup of course) ?

here is an example of regular error drawable

[image: error drawable always right]

so since the text entered is RTL i would like the pop up to show up at the LEFT side of the EditText

i tried to apply custom drawable , but [Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html) doesnt seem to have any setGravity method.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible by normal means, however you can extend the Android TextView class and change the layout that Android uses to inflate the popup. I haven't tried this myself but it could work.

I did a quick look in the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java) of TextView and found this line

```
final TextView err = (TextView) inflater.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.textview_hint,
                   null);
```

Which references to [this](https://code.google.com/p/jota-text-editor/source/browse/trunk/res/layout/textview_hint.xml?r=56) layout.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_inline_error"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
/>
```

Adding gravity here could do the trick. A similar approach for the drawable could apply.

Answer (score -2):

It's over a year, but if it helps anyone else, you can use:

```
myEdit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_error, 0, 0, 0);
```

but it will stay until you remove it

```
myEdit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: The question wasn't about setting the drawable programmatically it was about changing the gravity of the drawable.