# setError position on left side of Edittext in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to set setError view on left side of android EditText.  I am developing an application in Arabic language.  I Have tried layout direction. But still the setError showing on the right side of EditText.

Normal seterror:

[image: error drawable always right]

I found this answer

[Change EditText setError drawable gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173785/change-edittext-seterror-drawable-gravity)

But still don't know how to do it correctly

Comment: urPhone.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='white'>"+Activity.getResources().getString(R.string.enter_nmbr)+"</font>"));
   
   urPhone.requestFocus();

Comment: Can you provide some additional information:  Is your phone in the arabic locale?  How are you setting the layout direction?  Can you include some code in your actual question? - Including this information in your question means you are more likely to get a good response.

Comment: @SandeepCg Code generally looks like spilled Alphabits when posted in comments.  Please edit your main post and add it in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change EditText setError drawable gravity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173785/change-edittext-seterror-drawable-gravity)